# Google OAuth2 fails to redirect back to site, instead takes me to Google's My Account Page

Tags: google-oauth

I am using Google's PHP API client within a Laravel application to authorize a user via OAuth2 for the Analytics read-only API. I've used similar code on a previous project without issues, but this time it takes me to either Google's My Account page, or YouTube's account page, depending on the account I try to authorize with.

I have verified it is receiving the correct redirect_uri.

Here's some relevant code:

```
$google = new \Google_Client();

$google->setAuthConfig(resource_path('../client_secrets.json'));
$google->setRedirectUri(url()->to('/google/authorize'));
$google->addScope(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$google->setAccessType("offline");
$google->setApprovalPrompt('force');

// No code? Then we need to authorize with Google.
if (! $request->has('code')) {
    $authUrl = $google->createAuthUrl();
    return redirect()->to($authUrl);
}
```

Comment: Im a little confused what does YouTube have to do with Google analytics.

Comment: @DaImTo I have no idea! Was just providing all of the information. One email account that I used redirected me to the YouTube account page, where other 2 I have tried both redirected me Google's My Account page.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.

Turns out Google was redirecting properly but for some reason the code wasn't recognizing it had the `code` query value attached properly. Split the redirect to a different method and got it working that way.